# How can I clean my feet?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

I have a bad habit of not cleaning my feet while having a shower. As a result layers of dirt and dead skin accumulates on my feet for months. My feet's skin color looks totally different than the rest of my body.

How can I clean my feet?

I tried apple cider vinegar, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks "without much labor"... as you have discovered feet are not self-cleaning.

After getting foot problems, I was advised not to use soap, solvents, brushes or abrasives. Here is the method:

- Attend to the feet last, to allow time for their skin to soften.
- Lean against the wall of the shower so as to keep your balance.
- Lift one leg and support its foot with one hand, under the spray.
- With a finger of the other hand, thoroughly scrub between and under each toe.
- With the palm of that hand, scrub the heel, sole, edges and the top of the foot.
- Repeat for the other foot.
- After the shower, dry your feet thoroughly, especially between the toes.

This method removes dirt and dead skin. But don't expect your feet to recover from their poor state immediately. Just scrub them with your hands vigorously every time you bathe.

Answer (score 1):

Get a shower stool, they are not very expensive. I have one that you can adjust the height by the legs. Sit down and very comfortable and safe from falling.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a foot peeling mask. Many well-known companies sell them world wide, so they are easy to find. Simply follow the instructions on the packaging and watch your feet shed any dirt and dead skin you may have on your feet.